# Dynamically setting element text including formatting

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set the text dynamically when a link is clicked on. This is what I have so far:

```
<a href="www.somelinkhere.com" onclick="getElementById('setText').innerHTML='text to replace'" target="someIFrame">Link Description</a>

<div id="setText">Default text</div>
```

I loop through an array using PHP to determine the 'text to replace' text. This works fine when I'm just dealing with strings, however some of text in the array has formatting like the following and when this happens I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" error:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Ut euismod ex erat, id faucibus ex cursus vel.</p>
```

This is what is being passed:

```
<a href="www.somelinkhere.com" onclick="getElementById('setText').innerHTML='<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Ut euismod ex erat, id faucibus ex cursus vel.</p>
'" target="someIFrame">Link Description</a>
```

How can I make sure that when the text is replaced, the output is actually two paragraphs without the p tags?

Comment: Are you asking how to make new lines in html? Question is really unclear

Comment: If you are using new lines in the php that will make the string invalid in javascript without escaping the line breaks. Putting the html into a hidden element would be a btter approach than trying to put it all in `onclick` attribute

Comment: Agree - The newline is the issue ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the suggestion posted by @charlietfl to use the hidden attribute, then replaced onclick with a jQuery function that will toggle the hidden attribute depending on which link was being clicked.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really a good idea to supply larger sections of html in an html attribute but if you insist, you can do it like shown below:

```html
<a href="www.somelinkhere.com" onclick="document.getElementById('setText').innerHTML='&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Ut euismod ex erat, id faucibus ex cursus vel.&lt;/p&gt;'" target="someIFrame">Link Description</a>
<div id="setText">target</div>
```

The trick is to replace each occurence of `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Also remove any line feeds
(= newline characters) from the string.

As @charlietfl commented above, the real issue are the line feeds. The tags can actually remain as they are. Just tested.